# Fresh install of Windows Server 2008 R2 refuses to update

Tags: windows-server-2008

So I just received a brand new systemax server two weeks ago.  Installed Server 2008 on a preinstalled raid1, updated, started installing drivers and exchange '10.

Well, the raid1 started experiencing some issues and since I hadn't done much to the box I decided to wipe it out and set it up again.  This solved my raid issues.

Well, now I've reinstalled Server 2008 R2 and it refuses to update.  I've gotten a few different errors.  Googling them usually gives me Vista pages suggesting that I rename the updates folder, restart services, etc.  I've tried all of this without luck.  I've tried manually updating .net, I've tried manually installing service pack 1(it says its already installed), I've tried updating with the stock nic drivers and the drivers which came with the system, I've tried teaming the nics(load balancing mode) and also leaving them unteamed.  I also tried an "update readiness" package.  Nothing has helped.

Currently, Windows Update will be "Checking for updates" for about twenty minutes and then give me this error: 8024402f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are showing seems to be related to connectivity (WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS).  However if this is a new system I would just rebuild it again as clearly something is not installed properly.

Comment: I've done two reinstalls, the most recent with freshly burned media.. willing to reinstall again if you think it will help, is there any specific step I should be taking/looking out for?

Comment: Have to agree with this, the last point especially - if its a new install then by the time you troubleshoot something like this, fix it and make sure its not going to bite you again later, you could just as easily have re-installed from scratch and got on with something else.

Comment: if you've done 2 reinstalls and have the same issue the next thing I would do is redownload the ISO file and reburn.  If out of the box you cannot apply any updates I would verify that the nic card (as well as all of the rest of the system) is on the HCL.

Comment: Re-downloaded, reburned, reinstalled, same issue.. I'm downloading a windows server 2008 r2 with sp1 iso provided by techsoup, is there another (safe) place to download this or a similar iso?

Comment: if the image is not provided by Microsoft I would suggest you give them a call to see if the license you have is valid.  Typically you would have an actual microsoft download site to get a copy from.  See http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/licensing-options/for-industries.aspx#tab=4 for charity licensing

Comment: Well, the iso we have seems to match the iso provided by Microsoft, but I downloaded from Microsoft licensing anyway.  Still the same issue, sadly.  Now I'm going to try downloading 2008 R2 without sp1 streamed in and see if that is any different.

Comment: are there any firewalls between windowsupdate and the server that might be causing connectivity problems?  do other exsisting servers on the same subnet have this issue?

Comment: We've got a cisco 2811 sitting between the server and windows update.. this is the only server 2008 box I have, the rest of them are 2003.  The only even remotely similar problem I had was with an ubuntu desktop which had extremely limited bandwidth until I made a few tweaks.  The ubuntu box couldn't download faster than a few kb a second.  Optimizations in this thread solved the problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=872346

Comment: OK so presuming that the cab files are downloading correctly something is preventing the server from processing them properly.  Is there any antivirus or anything else installed prior to WU running?

Comment: No antivirus, actually the last install I did the first thing I tried was WU.  Then tweaked, then WU again, then installed net drivers and tried WU again

Comment: have you tried downloading manually downloading an update using one of the 2003 servers and applying the patch to the 2008 R2 system manaually?  that should at least tell you if the problem is the network or something else

Comment: Well, I tried Windows Server 2008 R2 with no sp1... same issue.. I could try manually downloading an update with my 03 boxes or my own desktop, which update would you reccomend?  The few I've tried were slipstreamed into my sp1 install..

Comment: If I understand what you are saying you were able to apply Sp1 post install but after that WU fails?

Comment: I installed vanilla 2003 R2 without sp1 slipstreamed in, tried wu(fail), installed sp1, update fails again

Comment: so another test to verify that cab processing is functional is to (prior to sp1 install) pick any update, download and install.  I'm pretty confident that if Sp1 installed that the problem isn't local to the server (but is isolated to the network) but I'm not positive that an SP update is processed the same as a "normal" update.

Comment: Woohoo!  I'm really not sure what fixed it, but its fixed.  I was previously just installing only the drivers that I figured it needed for the update after each reinstall, such as network stuff.  I downloaded the latest of everything, including storage and display, and my vanilla 2008r2 install is now updating.  I can't explain this.. but it works, so woohoo!  Thanks for all of your help folks.

Comment: so it sounds like you needd the proper drivers to initiate communications properly